# Flask - WTForm - save form to db

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, wtforms, flask-wtforms

I have problem with saving form (wtf) to (sqlalchemy) db ,form is rendering ,but after submit nothing happens ...

e.g. :

```
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Dec/2013 10:30:24] "POST /add/ HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

I was trying to save without validators

e.g. :

```
name = TextField('Task Name')
```

and i was trying to save form other way :

```
if request.method == 'POST' and form.validate():
            new_task = Tasks(
                         form.name.data,
                         form.due_date.data,
                         form.priority.data,
                         form.posted_date.data,
                         session['user_id'],
                         form.category.data,
                         form.super_category.data,
                         form.description.data
                        )
            db.session.add(new_task)
            db.session.commit()
```

And code below :

models :

```
# -*- coding: utf-8; -*-

from app import db
import datetime


class Tasks(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = "tasks"

    task_id = db.Column(db.Integer,primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(255),nullable=False)
    description = db.Column(db.Text,nullable=False)
    priority = db.Column(db.Integer,nullable=False)
    posted_date = db.Column(db.DATE,nullable=False)
    status = db.Column(db.Integer,default=1,nullable=False)
    category = db.Column(db.String(255),nullable=False)
    super_category = db.Column(db.String(255),nullable=False)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer,db.ForeignKey('users.id'))

    def __init__(self,name,due_date,priority,posted_date,users_id,category,super_category,description):
        self.name = name
        self.due_date = due_date
        self.priority = priority
        self.posted_date = posted_date
        self.user_id = users_id
        self.category = category
        self.super_category = super_category
        self.description = description
```

forms :

```
 # -*- coding: utf-8; -*-
from wtforms import Form,validators
from wtforms import TextField,DateField,IntegerField,SelectField,TextAreaField
from wtforms.validators import required,Email,EqualTo,Length
from wtforms import PasswordField

class AddTask(Form):
  name = TextField('Task Name',validators=[required()])
  due_date = DateField('Date Due (mm/dd/yyyy)',validators=[required()],format='%m/%d/%Y')
  priority = SelectField('Priority',validators=[required()],choices=[('1','1'),('2','2'),('3','3'),('4','4'),('5','5')])
  description = TextAreaField('Description',validators=[required()])
  posted_date = DateField('Posted Date (mm/dd/yyyy)',validators=[required()],format='%m/%d/%Y')
  category = SelectField('Category',validators=[required()],choices=[('foobar','foobar'),('foobar2','foobar2')])
  super_category = SelectField('Super_category',validators=[required()],choices=[('foobar3','foobar3'),('foobar4','foobar4'),('foobar5','foobar5')])
  user_id = SelectField('User',validators=[required()],choices=[('1','1'),('2','2'),('3','3'),('4','4'),('5','5')])
```

views :

```
@app.route('/add/',methods=['GET','POST'])
@login_required
def new_task():
    form = AddTask(request.form,csrf_enabled=True)
    if request == 'POST' and form.validate():
        form_tasks = Tasks()
        form.populate_obj(form_tasks)
        db.session.add(form_tasks)
        db.session.commit()
        return redirect(url_for('tasks'))
    return render_template('form.html',form=form)
```

form.html :

```
{% extends "layout2.html" %}
{% from 'common.html' import edit_field %}
{%  block content %}
<div class='edit well offset 2 span8'>
  <form method='post' class="form-horizontal">
    <legend> Add task </legend>
        {{ edit_field(form.name , class="span3") }}
        {{ edit_field(form.due_date , class="span3", type="datetime") }}
        {{ edit_field(form.priority, class="span3") }}
        {{ edit_field(form.description, rows="5" ,class="span3", placeholder="foobar" ) }}
        {{ edit_field(form.posted_date, class="span3",type="datetime") }}
        {{ edit_field(form.category, class="span3") }}
        {{ edit_field(form.super_category, class="span3") }}
<div class="form-actions">
<button type="submit" class="btn">SAVE</button>
</div>
</form>
</div>
{%  endblock    %}
```

common.html :

```
{% macro edit_field(field,catch_kwargs=true) %}
<div class="control-group{% if field.errors  %} error {% endif %}">
    {{  field.label(class="control-label") }}
<div class="controls">
    {{  field(**kwargs)  }}
    {% for error in field.errors %}
    <span class="help-inline">{{error}}</span>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
</div>
{% endmacro %}
```

Comment: when in doubt, log `form.errors`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to put anti-forgery token somewhere within the form.
Add the following in your template file, inside the form tag:

```
{{ form.hidden_tag() }}
```

This renders hidden field similar to

```
<input id="csrf_token" name="csrf_token" type="hidden" value="xxxxxx">
```

Putting it together with your `form.html` file we are getting:

```
{% extends "layout2.html" %}
{% from 'common.html' import edit_field %}
{% block content %}
<div class='edit well offset 2 span8'>
    <form method='post' class="form-horizontal">
        {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
        <legend>Add task</legend>
        {{ edit_field(form.name , class="span3") }}
        {{ edit_field(form.due_date , class="span3", type="datetime") }}
        {{ edit_field(form.priority, class="span3") }}
        {{ edit_field(form.description, rows="5" ,class="span3"
                     , placeholder="foobar" ) }}
        {{ edit_field(form.posted_date, class="span3",type="datetime") }}
        {{ edit_field(form.category, class="span3") }}
        {{ edit_field(form.super_category, class="span3") }}
        <div class="form-actions">
            <button type="submit" class="btn">SAVE</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 5):

The solution is :

add `hidden_tag()` - Thanks vittore !

import "form" from `flask_wtf` not from wtforms .

remove "request.form" from `new_task()`

Now code looks like this and it's working ! - thanks everyone for help .

```
@app.route('/add/',methods=['GET','POST'])
@login_required
def new_task():
    form = AddTask(csrf_enabled=True)
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        new_task = Tasks(
                          form.name.data,
                          form.due_date.data,
                          form.priority.data,
                          form.posted_date.data,
                          session['user_id'],
                          form.category.data,
                          form.super_category.data,
                          form.description.data
                        )
        db.session.add(new_task)
        db.session.commit()
        return redirect(url_for('tasks'))
    else:
        flash_errors(form)
    return render_template('form.html',form=form)
```

Comment: Hi @Mammoth, welcome to the community. I see you are new here so wanted to suggest that the polite thing to do is to accept vittore's answer. I believe you can even update his response with your solution.

Comment: Hi @jwogrady , i accepted Vittore's answer - but i don't know how to update his response :))

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your form.validate() is returning False, try testing without validate check and see what happens, also im not seeing csrf token being passed anywhere.