# Python Flask Save Form Data to DB

Tags: python, flask-sqlalchemy

I am new to Flask and I am trying to save form data from a Flask form to database using SQLAlchemy and I am not having any luck.  I have tried several methods from research I found both here and outside of this forum.

When I take the simplistic route, the web form works and I can enter data but it will not populate the DB.

----Models----

```
class QIDMapping(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    qid_number = db.Column(db.Integer)
    br_field_name = db.Column(db.String(75))
    vendor_field = db.Column(db.String(75))
```

----Forms----

```
class QIDForm(Form):
    qidnumber = IntegerField('qidnumber', validators=[DataRequired()])
    brfieldname = StringField('brfieldname', validators=[DataRequired()])
    vendorfieldname = StringField('vendorfieldname')
```

----Views----

```
from flask import render_template, flash, redirect, session, url_for, 
request, g
from flask_wtf import form
from app import app, db
from .forms import QIDForm
from .models import User, QIDMapping
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy


@app.route('/qidmapping', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def qid_map_update():
    form = QIDForm()
    return render_template('qidmapping.html',
                            title='QID Mapping',
                            form=form)
```

----qidmapping.html----

```
{% block content %}

    <h1>Map QIDs to Vendor File</h1>
    <form action="" method="POST">
        {{form.hidden_tag()}}
        <p>
            Please enter the QID, BrassRing Field Name and Vendor Tag
            <br>
            <h2>QID Number {{ form.qidnumber(size=25) }}<br></h2>
            <h2>BR Field   {{ form.brfieldname(size=25) }}<br></h2>
            <h2>Vendor Field   {{ form.vendorfieldname(size=25) }}<br></h2>
        </p>
        <p><br>
        </p>
        <p><input type="submit" value="Save Fields">
        </p>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

I have also tried the method in this post [Flask - WTForm - save form to db](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20837209/flask-wtform-save-form-to-db)
and when I do, I get a Method Not Allowed error and I'm not sure why.

----view for question 20837209 format----

```
@app.route('/qidmapping', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def qid_map_update():
    form = QIDForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        newform = (
            form.qidnumber.data,
            form.brfieldname.data,
            form.vendorfieldname.data
            )
        db.session.add(newform)
        db.session.commit()
        return redirect('/qidmapping')
    return render_template('qidmapping.html',
                            title='QID Mapping',
                            form=form)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try replacing

```
newform = (
            form.qidnumber.data,
            form.brfieldname.data,
            form.vendorfieldname.data
            )
db.session.add(newform)
```

with

```
m = QIDMapping()
m.qid_number = form.qidnumber.data
m.br_field_name = form.brfieldname.data
m.vendor_field = form.vendorfieldname.data
db.session.add(m)
```

... and if that doesn't work. Do your standard POST troubleshooting:

1) Verify POST request

2) Ensure CSRF is working correctly.

3) Log validation errors / success

4) Check for DB exceptions

Comment: Thank you Peter, I will give this a try!

Comment: No problem, glad to help.